# Relationship of oxygen dissolved in water with bubble time and temperature

Tags: solubility, gas-laws, solvents

I'm using the [Winkler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winkler_titration) to calculate oxygen dissolved in water. This is at the temperatures 20, 30, 40, and $\pu{50 ^\circ{}C}$ and I bubbled a controlled amount of oxygen in through the reaction of manganese oxide and hydrogen peroxide. At all the different temperatures I bubbled air for 0, 20, 40, 60, or $\pu{80 s}$, respectively. I have found data online for max solubility of oxygen at different temperatures but no data for this sort of relationship. The results I collected for now are only these but they make no sense (I changed the $\ce{O2}$ bubbling after this).

[image]

Comment: It seems you have a systematic error in titration at 50 C. The solubility of oxygen in water at various temperatures must be known very well.

Comment: Consider text based tables, using SE markdown orvMathJax formatting. // You may find useful these links:
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [formulas/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) ( not to be applied to titles ) and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: I assume the kinetics of oxygen saturation has exponential shape of transition between initial and final value, the latter being T dependent as well as the kinetic constant for that.

Comment: @Poutnik do you know where I could find sample data of a similar experiment? I've been looking for it everywhere but I probably just don't know the right keywords to search with. I have found many values for maximum saturation but this shouldn't be what is happening as I am not trying to make it reach maximum saturation. It is to my understanding this has something to do with Henry's Law of solubility of gases.

Comment: See [engineeringtoolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/oxygen-solubility-water-d_841.html) for charts and tables of oxygen solibility data.